# What makes a furnace pilot valve whistle?

Tags: hvac, furnace, noise

I have a furnace that started whistling, recently.

I have read that [gas pressure changes can cause this](http://www.diychatroom.com/f17/sort-whistling-noise-standing-pilot-furnace-gas-valve-possibly-188854/).  Others have remarked how [seasonal gas changes](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/gas-oil-home-heating-furnaces/189543-gas-furnace-whistles.html#post674962) can lead to a properly-adjusted furnace to suddenly operate differently.

I have adjusted the pilot adjustment screw, in an attempt to change the amount of gas flowing through the pilot.  180 degrees turn in either direction did not cause any observable change in the gas flow (size of he flame).  The 'whistling' persisted evenly through that change.

What else can cause a pilot to whistle?  Or, perhaps, is the matter likely that I need to adjust the pilot screw farther than I did?

Comment: Assuming you've provided all of the relevant information, you definitely need to continue to adjust the screw.  This same phenomenon can be seen when starting up an oxy-acetylene torch:  Whistling occurs at some sweet spot of flow/combustion corresponding to the resonant frequency of the orifice.  It can come and go depending on your adjustment of the gas flows.

Comment: Your gas supply pressure should not change with the seasons. Depending on supply type, the mains pressure might change but delivery pressure to your appliance should be regulated by a device owned by the utility company. Call your supplier and tell them you think there is a problem, they will come out and check the equipment for free. You will then be assured that it is a local issue with your appliance and not the supply.

Comment: I've tried 4 rotations in and out, on the pilot adj. no change in the pilot flame size or color. That sounds not-right.